# Is it Possible to Draw Transparent Boxes in GL11 Quads?

Tags: java, lwjgl

I'm wondering, can I draw transparent boxes in GL11 in JWJGL? I'm also wondering if I can draw these so I can have the screen turn red when you die but you can still see the background.

Comment: How do I do it Though?

Comment: If you're using immediate mode, `glColor4f` where the 4th value is transparency, if you're using vertex arrays, enable `GL_COLOR_ARRAY`.

Answer (score 0):

I used this for alpha/transparency:

```
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

You have to render everything behind the box first. Render the background before the box or you'll have an x-ray.